# Am trying to use an avatar image from user meta profile as the background for a template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is probably simple for most people but I'm pulling my hair out lol

So here is test code I tried that will display the url string "/uploads/files/file1.jpg" of the avatar of the logged in user correctly when the page is viewed in browser:

```
 <?php 
 $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
 $key = 'user_avatar'; 
 $single = true; 
 $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
 echo $user_last; 
 ?>
```

That displays the ending url of the image I want to use as the background image, but maybe I need the full fqdn path?

So when I add this code to set background on the body it doesn't work (have tried many variations and echo, quotes, no quotes, etc.) but obviously doing something wrong:

```
<body style="background-image:url(<?php get_user_meta('$user_id, $key, $single');?>); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Thanks you people!

Comment: Maybe <?php get_user_meta("$user_id, $key, $single");?> instead of <?php get_user_meta('$user_id, $key, $single');?>

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I've tried single, double, no quotes and a space after/before the ( ) and other stuff, but just get a normal page with no background

Comment: See answer, did you try echoing it?

Comment: It seems your function just returns the value, implied by `$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single )` part. Try echoing it in HTML as others suggested.

Comment: I just tried those two and got nothing

Comment: Here is the body tag from the source:

<body style="background-image:url(/uploads/files/main1b-1513703314.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">

Comment: Try <?php ".".get_user_meta("$user_id, $key, $single");?> if the current file is in the same folder where the uploads folder is located. And if the upload folder is located outside the current file's location folder (sibling directory of the current file's parent directory), use ".." instead of "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress normally has the `uploads` folder in the `wp-content` sub directory as it's default installation. To get the initial directory path, use `site_url()` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

So the code will be:

```
 <?php 
 $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
 $key = 'user_avatar'; 
 $single = true; 
 $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
 //echo $user_last; 
 ?>

<body style="background-image:url('<?php echo site_url().'/wp-content'. $user_last; ?>'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

** Need to also add an `echo` to output the final concatenated string.

EDIT: (based on Dave in DC's comment) check slashes (`/`) before and after the `wp-content` it might have an extra one (or one needed) depending on if `site_url()` and `$user_last` already has a slash.

Comment: Thanks signal, that worked!  (and thanks to others), I don't know how I missed that little piece, but it was not returning the 'wp-content' part, so it was failing to load the image. I had to add a slash before the wp-content (not after), so the exact line that ended up working for me was:

<body style="background-image:url('<?php echo site_url().'/wp-content'. $user_last; ?>'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">

Comment: Ok. I updated the information based on what you said. Thanks.